# Failed to eject 32GB SD Card - SG driver

Tags: xubuntu, sd-card, eject

I am running Xubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
I cannot seem to safely eject any SD card (USB key/memory sticks are fine.)

I can unmount it, but I can't achieve a safe ejection.
I get the following error:

Failed to eject 32GB Volume.
Error ejecting /dev/mmcblk0: Command-line eject /dev/mmcblk0
exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: 'not an sg device, or old sg driver'

stderr: eject unable to eject, last error: Invalid argument

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is “power”. When you `unmount` a storage device, you tell the OS to finish writing anything that’s still in the buffer and cleanly close the file system. When you `eject`, you tell the OS to do the same thing as `unmount` with the additional step of disconnecting power to the device. SD devices needn’t have power cut from the reader to be safely removed.

This might naturally raise the question “then why not handle this more gracefully?”, but I cannot answer that question